# Swift unresolved identifiers in AWS Cognito and DynamoDB

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am integrating AWS DynamoDB and Cognito by following the steps from their official documentation. I have installed the dependencies from Cocoapods and they installed successfully.

However I am still getting error of unresolved identifiers as shown in the below screenshot:

[image: as shown in the below screenshot.]

**Related import statements are:**

```
import AWSCore
import AWSCognito
import AWSDynamoDB
```

**Things I have tried till now:**

- Updating pods (updated successfully)
- Xcode -> Preferences -> Location -> DerivedData
- Moved the contents of folder derived data to trash.

Comment: think you have to declare that variable first before using it.

Comment: Okay, and what about cognitoId?

Comment: tap on the red breakpoint and see what xcode suggest

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the dependencies (AWS SDK) via cocoapods. The instructions are mentioned in README.txt of the app download. Once the dependencies are installed, you need to close the `.xcodeproj` and open the `.xcworkspace` file and then, the app should work.

Thanks,
Rohan

Answer (score 0):

You may need to `import AWSCognitoIdentityProvider` for the variable `cognitoId`